# Reading and printing chinese characters using fread() and printf()?

Tags: c, unicode, fread, chinese-locale

I am trying to read Chinese characters from an infile, and I have found a few questions on the subject here but nothing that works for me or suits my needs. I am using the fread() implementation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523951/reading-unicode-characters-from-file-in-c), but it is not working. I am running Linux.

```
  #define UNICODE
  #ifdef UNICODE
  #define _UNICODE
  #else
  #define _MBCS
  #endif

  #include <locale.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <wchar.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
         FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
         wchar_t test[2] = L"\u4E2A";
         setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
         printf("%ls\n", test); //test
         wcscpy(test, L"\u4F60"); //test
         printf("%ls\n", test); //test
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                 fread(test, 2, 2, infile);
                 printf("%ls\n", test);
         }
 return 0;
  }
```

I use the following text file to test it:

```
 一个人
 两本书
 三张桌子
 我喜欢一个猫
```

and the program outputs:

```
个 
你
������
```

Anyone have any wisdom on the subject?

Edit: Also, that's all of my code because I'm not sure where it fails. There's some stuff in there where I test to make sure I can print unicode wchars that isn't entirely relevant to the question.

Comment: Windows or Linux? If windows, try opening the file as binary `fopen(argv[1],"rb")`

Comment: Can you please remove the line numbers from your code sample? They make it hard to execute the code when I try to help you.

Comment: @user3386109 not just that, you might want to open it as a wide-character oriented stream.

Comment: Yeah I'll remove the numbers now and add that I'm using Linux, one second.

Comment: You need to check how the file is encoded. (utf-8, utf-16, utf-32)? And you need to check if your file included a BOM.

Comment: It is Unicode utf-8. I hexdumped the file and I do not see a BOM.

Comment: As you are using linux, it might just work if you don't define `UNICODE`, but you will have to use a larger buffer. But also take a look at http://site.icu-project.org/ in case you need to convert.

Comment: The `fread` will only work for utf-16. With utf-8, each character takes anywhere from 1 to 6 bytes, so you have to read a byte at a time until you have a full character. How you convert the utf-8 character to a `wchar_t` for printf is beyond me.

Comment: So if I convert my test file to utf-16, would that hypothetically work?

Comment: If the input file is utf-16, you still have a couple problems to deal with. **First**, although most utf-16 characters are one `wchar_t` (2 bytes), there are some that are two `wchar_t` (4 bytes). Since the `fread` always reads 4 bytes, it may get a) two chars of two bytes each b) one char that's four bytes c) a two-byte char and the first half of a 4-byte char.  **Second**, the `fread` doesn't properly NUL terminate the string for `printf`. Which is to say that `test` needs to be `wchar_t test[3]` and you need to add the NUL terminator before calling `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to read a UTF-8 (or rather a locale charmap) file one codepoint at a time you can use `fscanf` as below. But do note, this is **codepoints** not **characters**, characters may consist of multiple codepoints because of combining codes and some of the codepoints are most definitely not printable.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE   *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    wchar_t test[2] = L"\u4E2A";
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("%ls\n", test);  //test
    wcscpy(test, L"\u4F60");        //test
    printf("%ls\n", test);  //test
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fscanf(infile, "%1ls", test);
        printf("%ls\n", test);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Most of the time you probably won't need to use the locale functionality because UTF-8 generally just works if you treat it as an opaque encoding. Part of this is because **all** non ASCII characters have **all** their component bytes in the 128..253 range (not a typo, 254 and 255 are unused) another part is that the bytes 128..159 are always continuation bytes all the start bytes for *characters* are 160..253 which means an error will just break one character not the rest of the stream. (Okay, codepoints vs characters is only really there to try to convince you that dividing UTF-8 up into "characters" probably won't do what you want).

Comment: This is a good answer, thank you. in a few hours I will try to run the same program with UTF-16 input instwad. The complexity of the "codepoints" seems to not be worth it.

Comment: UTF-16 has every problem that UTF-8 has plus some, it's a bad choice for any OS.  For example "" is four bytes in UTF-16. It does have one rather large advantage on Windows in that much of the OS-API uses it, but even that doesn't really make it a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling `fread` to read two 2-byte values in each call; however, the characters you want to read have 3-byte UTF-8 encodings. In general, you need to decode the UTF-8 stream as a whole, not in fixed-sized byte chunks.