# Read unicode characters from file in C

Tags: c, windows, unicode, character-encoding, console

I am trying to read a UTF-8 string from a .csv file, then write it in console.

**a.csv** content:

```
Gijón
```

After a full day of research on the topic I have found that the supposedly proper way to perform such operation should be something similar to the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("locale: %s\n", locale);

    const int MAX_LINE_SIZE = 1024;
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    wchar_t wline[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    // Attempt 0: no special handling
    FILE* stream = fopen("a.csv", "r");
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stream);
    printf("%s\n", line); // Expected to print "GijÃ³n", prints "GijÃ³n"
    fclose(stream);

    // Attempt 1: mbstowcs
    mbstowcs(wline, line, MAX_LINE_SIZE);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", wline); // Expected to print "Gijón", prints "GijÃ³n"

    // Attempt 2: fgetws
    stream = fopen("a.csv", "r");
    fgetws(wline, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stream);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", wline); // Expected to print "Gijón", prints "GijÃ³n"
    fclose(stream);

    // Attempt 3: _wfopen
    stream = _wfopen(L"a.csv", L"rb");
    fgetws(wline, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stream);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", wline); // Expected to print "Gijón", prints ""
    fclose(stream);

    // Printing command line parameter
    mbstowcs(wline, argv[1], MAX_LINE_SIZE);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", wline); // Properly prints "Gijón"
}
```

But running this program results in:

```
.\myprogram.exe Gijón
locale: Spanish_Spain.1252
GijÃ³n
GijÃ³n

Gijón
```

I don't think it's a problem with the console itself as `argv[1]` conversion works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this for Windows or Linux/Mac?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: What is `_wfopen`? This is not part of standard C or is it? It appears to be Microsoft-specific.

Comment: I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523951/reading-unicode-characters-from-file-in-c
It doesn't seem to work for me anyway, just a desperate attempt to make it work

Comment: FYI on a Mac, where I was able to run your whole program _except_ for the Windows-specific `_wfopen`, I saw it print `Gijón` every single time. I hope a Windows expert chimes in here. I do know the Mac Terminal program is UTF-8 by default, so I suspect, but cannot be sure, that there is some console setting in Windows that you will need to check. Sorry no access to Windows here at the moment.

Comment: The o-acute has a unicode encoding of 0x00F3. In UTF-8 it needs to bytes, 0xC3 and 0xB3. These are the two chars A with ~ above and superscript three which you see.

Comment: Yes, but how do I make the program print it as a single unicode character again?

Comment: `Gijón` just uses ANSI code page. Your file probably contains a character that's looks similar to `ó`. Open the file with text editor and copy/paste in to your question.

Comment: The content of the file is already copy-pasted from the file into the question. I think your answer below points in the right direction. I will disclose my doubts as comments there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wchar_t` and wide char functions (`wfopen` etc.) are used mainly in Windows to handle Unicode in UTF16 encoding.

UTF8 uses `char` and the same ASCII compatible C functions (`fopen` etc.) To read UTF8, you can use the same C functions for ASCII.

Windows does not have full support to read and display UTF8, therefore you have to convert between UTF8 and UTF16 in order to properly display the text. Windows 10 does have UTF8 support for console Windows, see relevant topics.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* filename = "a.csv";
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    char buf[1000];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);

    if(strlen(buf) > 2)
        if(strncmp(buf, "\xFF\xFE", 2) == 0)
        {
            printf("UTF16-LE\n");
            fclose(fp);
            fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
            wchar_t wbuf[1000] = { 0 };
            fgets((char*)wbuf, sizeof(buf), fp);
            MessageBoxW(0, wbuf, L"UTF16-LE", 0);
            return 0;
        }

    if(strlen(buf) > 3)
        if(strncmp(buf, "\xEF\xBB\xBF", 3) == 0)
            printf("UTF8 with BOM\n");

    //assume UTF8 and convert to UTF16:
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t *utf16 = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, utf16, size);

    MessageBoxA(0, buf, "ANSI", 0);
    MessageBoxW(0, utf16, L"UTF8 converted", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If source file is UTF8 then you basically treat it as ASCII. Just be careful with functions like `strtok` which cannot handle input characters outside the ASCII range. The only other complication is when you try to print it in Windows. Use the example below with custom `printf` function:

```
void printf_utf8(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int len = _vscprintf(format, args) + 1; 
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    vsprintf(buf, format, args);

    //convert to UTF16 and print
    int wbuf_size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t *wbuf = malloc((wbuf_size + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, -1, wbuf, wbuf_size);

    DWORD temp;
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteConsoleW(h, wbuf, wcslen(wbuf), &temp, 0);

    free(wbuf);
    free(buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("a.csv", "r");
    if(!fp)
        return 0;
    char buf[1000];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
    printf_utf8("Test %s %d\n", buf, 123);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the text editor I'm using (notepad++) the file is encoded in UTF8. This code makes the popup "UTF8 converted" to properly display "Gijón" (+1). I have discovered an option in notepad to convert encoding in file to ANSI (which also has a character for ó), and makes my question code display "Gijón" properly. But my intention is to be able to handle a UTF8 encoded file.

Comment: Q. MultiByteToWideChar is windows platform specific. How a multiplatform solution would look like? is there any special treatment needed at all in linux?

Comment: Q2. How can strncmp identify the encoding of a file? (if this is perhaps a different SO question, it would be nice to have a link to it somewhere around here).

Comment: When you run that program did it print `"UTF8 with BOM"`? UTF8 files some times have BOM, sometimes they don't. If it has BOM then skip the first 3 bytes. For Linux/Mac just use normal C functions. Linux can read/display UTF8 just fine. For Windows it's the same thing, except you have to convert it to UTF16 when you want to show it to the user.

Comment: No, it didn't print `"UTF8 with BOM"`

Comment: Since Windows 8, the console allows writing UTF-8 via `WritFile` and `WriteConsoleA`. But even Windows 10 (release 1803) doesn't support reading UTF-8 from the console via `ReadFile` and `ReadConsoleA`. It's limited to 7-bit ASCII. It can't handle the variable-sized encoding of 2-4 bytes per code with non-ASCII UTF-8, so it replaces non-ASCII characters with ASCII NUL (i.e. `'\0'`). Maybe this is fixed in release 1809. It's worse prior to Windows 10, in which case trying to read non-ASCII characters as UTF-8 results in an empty read, which is commonly seen as end-of-file.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to convert the wide chars to the 1252 encoding. The 1252 encoding is a 8bit/char encoding and will only support a small subset of the unicode characters.
Maybe there are conversion functions/libraries available. But is seems not to be too complicated to write it yourself (big switch/case clause).